# Please help me With my SQLITE 2 problem:(

Tags: sqlite

How can i edit .sqlite file ? Can we convert it to convert to readable text format ?

Here is file link.. http://FastFreeFileHosting.com/file/52328/uploads-sqlite.html

Comment: What is your operating system and platform?

Answer (score 3):

You need the SQLite 2.x command line shell for your operating system to manipulate your `uploads.sqlite` file.

You can use it to get a full database dump as an [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) transaction:

```
$ sqlite uploads.sqlite .dump
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE 'temp' (
       hash text,
       file_id integer,
       file_name text,
       user_info text,
       date integer
    );
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('248283734d02fac7197b02b3cea7b25c',1,'blocklist.xml','199.27.128.60',20101207124952);
.
.
.
INSERT INTO temp VALUES('10f50e1f9266180306153b900233bdcd',20,'Joku.sis','175.40.26.96',20110103015449);
CREATE TABLE 'uploads' (
       id integer(32) not null primary key unique,
       filename text(100),
       date integer,
       user_info text,
       hash text
    );
INSERT INTO uploads VALUES(1,'blocklist.xml',20101207124943,'199.27.128.60','82d69cf46c45760176f7b214a5cf36b1');
.
.
.
INSERT INTO uploads VALUES(20,'Joku.sis',20110103015402,'175.40.26.96','43a61da540a8e97fedb180c8984a4d3b');
COMMIT;
```

You can also perform specific queries or updates using [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL):

```
$ sqlite uploads.sqlite
SQLite version 2.8.17
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> INSERT INTO uploads VALUES(21,'Joku.sis2',20110102015402,'175.40.26.97','43a61da540a8e97fedb180c8984a4d3b');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE date > 20101224000000;
19|tab-view.zip|20101230002321|27.97.29.98|5a9e7ff82c5a424fe5a19d97079b6dc7
20|Joku.sis|20110103015402|175.40.26.96|43a61da540a8e97fedb180c8984a4d3b
21|Joku.sis2|20110102015402|175.40.26.97|43a61da540a8e97fedb180c8984a4d3b
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a shell script to create an HTML or CSV file of the contents of the SQLite database. Will work in any OS (in windows, you will need to install some additional tools).

See `Using sqlite3 in a shell script` from [Command Line Shell For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) from the SQLite website. Or you could use a GUI tool.